# Website stopped appearing on Google results

Tags: seo, google, search

I have a website with a Page Rank 3. Yesterday it was listed in Google as the second link (under a specific Hebrew keyword). 12 hours later I checked it with my Google Monitor tool and it seems my website doesn't appear in Google search results anymore.

Comment: Could you give us the website URL?

Comment: Did you use bold on the Page Rank 3 like because your PR3 it should be ranking? PR has little to no effect on actual search results.

Comment: There enough reasons that a website could fall out of the Google index to fill a book.   I'm voting to close this question.  Please ask more specific questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely do what Sidg suggested and sign up for Webmaster Tools. This is your direct connection to Google in relation to your site.

To answer your question, it could be something as simple as Google's results haven't synchrnoized across all of their servers and datacenters yet. Google's servers span many different datacenters and your site may be ranked in one and non-existant in another. You said your site only ranked yesterday, give it some time and monitor the changes with Webmaster Tools.

Answer (score 0):

Login into webmaster. 
Goto **Health** and check if there is any error.

Also share the domain name.